# Which Android UI component can be used as Side-Info when scrolling?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have no idea how else to describe to question or form an understandable title so I'll just try.

There's a RecycleListView that's quite long. Each one of the list item has a card, inside that an image and some text etc...

I have some data (one word) for each card that I would like to show as the user scrolls but I have no idea what this type of component is even called.[image]

EDIT: Here's a represenation of where my thinking is going, not exactly what I am describing but it displays the idea quite well or at least the intention: [image]

Maybe there's a better solution to this. I don't want to use a textview, second list or another Tab/Activity. All I want, is to notify the user as they are scrolling (or not / doesn't matter whether the info is permanent).
I think this is not going into the right direction and I doubt I can fit an entire word into such a tiny vertical space, anyone got a better idea ?

Comment: A scrollbar is used to notify user if they are scrolling or not. The position of current scroll. and it automatically appears and disappears on user scrolling.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. The user knows that they are scrolling because the cards, images and textviews are moving. I am not in need of a scrollbar.
I need some type of scrollbar's (notice the 's) that grip only a certain amount of cards and give the lead to the next bar when card x with info x comes / info y ends.

Comment: At this point your question becomes really unclear. I can't understand what do you want.